# jQuery ajax content loaded in div, event ready

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-events, document-ready

I am dynamically loading content in a page using jQuery Ajax. The content contains images, so I need to know at what point all the images will be loaded, something like DOM Ready.

Initially content will be hidden. After the images were loaded successfully I display the div containing them. Is there a method to detect when the loaded content with Ajax is ready to display? Ajax `success` function is called when the text response is returned from server but I need to execute a function when is all loaded and images are loaded as well.

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking.  Are you asking when the content you requested via Ajax has been returned or are you asking when images that you have inserted into your document are all now loaded?

Comment: I am asking when images that I have inserted into my document are all loaded.

Comment: Please edit your question to be much more clear about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have just inserted a bunch of HTML into your document (containing some `<img>` tags) and you want to know when all those new images are loaded, you can do it like this.  Let's suppose that the dynamic content was all inserted into the `#root` object.  Right after you've inserted the dynamic contend, you can run this code:

```
function notifyWhenImagesLoaded(rootSelector, callback) {
    var imageList = $(rootSelector + " img");
    var imagesRemaining = imageList.length;

    function checkDone() {
        if (imagesRemaining === 0) {
            callback()
        }
    }

    imageList.each(function() {
        // if the image is already loaded, just count it
        if (this.complete) {
            --imagesRemaining;
        } else {
            // not loaded yet, add an event handler so we get notified
            // when it finishes loading
            $(this).load(function() {
                --imagesRemaining;
                checkDone();
            });
        }
    });
    checkDone();
}

notifyWhenImagesLoaded("#root", function() {
    // put your code here to run when all the images are loaded
});
```

You call this function after you've inserted the dynamic content.  It finds all images tags in the dynamic content and checks if any have already loaded.  If they have, it counts them.  If they haven't, then it installs a load event handler so it will get notified when the image loads.  When the last image finishes loading, it calls the callback.

Answer (score 0):

**ajax**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "myfile.*",
    data: {data : params}, 
    cache: false,
    success: function(return_data){
       //here you have the answer to Ajax
       //at this point you have the content ready for use
       //in your case here you would find the images that you got back from the file called by ajax
    }
});
```

Comment: When it triggers the event success means that the file was called back the requested data, and therefore are "ready" for use. Maybe I misunderstood the question

Comment: The question is unclear.  I've posted a comment asking for clarification.  Your answer just shows a typical ajax call.  The OP obviously wants something related to images in dynamically loaded content, but it's not entirely clear what they want.

Comment: @jfriend00, I know how to make an Ajax call. I need a event like DOM Ready.

Comment: @SpartakusMd - yes, I know.  I've added my own answer to show you how.  I'm not the one who wrote this answer.

Comment: @jfriend00, Sorry. The first part was for Nicolo.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the on method with load.
Count how many items you have in total and use the load event to have a number of total images loaded. You can even build a progress bar like this.

Something like that and after you have finished with the ajax call

```
$('img').on('load', function(){

  // Count items here      

});
```